# "Unsung Hero" requirement

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress, zero-score-badges

What exactly is the [Unsung hero badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero)'s requirement? The info text says:

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total.

The first part is pretty clear, 10 accepted answers with a zero score, but the second part 25% of total. What exactly is total, total answers, total accepted answers or ...?

Comment: It says more then 10 though so wouldn't that mean you need 11. If it said 10 or more it would be 10. Maybe @Jeff Atwood could give us some clarification?

Comment: @Gage: Yeah, I'm wondering the same with Tenacious; whether it requires 5 or 6 answers.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Accepted answers = Total accepted answers that are not self accept and not community wiki or deleted.

Both 10 and 25% refer to "Accepted Answers"

Comment: So, to clarify, if I have 20 accepted answers (as outlined above), 10 non-accepted answers, and 50000 self-accepted answers, I would get the badge, correct?

Comment: yes self accepts are totally ignored

Comment: @waffles Can we change the wording then? "*Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total accepted.*"

Comment: @DuncanJones It's been 5 (more) years, where's the wording change?

Comment: @Userthatisnotauser I don't work here :-)

Comment: @DuncanJones I know, just pointing out how little attention this has received! ;)