# Can somebody better explain the Tenacious badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

I just acquired the Tenacious badge but the description is leaving me wondering what exactly I've done to acquire it.

**Description:**

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total.

Comment: See [this answer on Unsung Hero](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57244/unsung-hero-requirement/57245#57245), only the numbers differ.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Basically, you have a ton of answers that have a score of zero and are also accepted.

In particular, you have more than 5 answers that have a score of zero and are accepted.  And, those zero-score-accepted answers make up at least 20% of your total accepted answers.

Comment: 20% of the total *accepted* answers, excluding CW and self-accept.

Comment: This leads me to wonder...who out there is accepting answers without upvoting them?  That just seems strange.

Comment: @beska: New users with < 15 rep.

Comment: This accepted answer is wrong. I have 281 total answers, and 7 unupvoted but accepted answers. Georg is right: It must be 20% of the **accepted** answers (... bla, bla, CW/self accept). And that's the problem of the tooltip-description too. **20% of what** is unclear.

Comment: @user, are you sure of this?

Comment: Yes, feel free to browse my profile. I was awarded the Tenacious-badge today, and was astonished, and tried to find out, what it is for, and stumbled across this 20% rule.

Comment: It is unclear to me why this is an achievement. Shouldn't you be rewarded for accepted answers *with* upvotes, rather than for answers *without* upvotes?

Comment: I think the person who asks the question should accept the answer that  worked.  Others should upvote answers which they feel are good and which answers the question correctly instead of writing the same answer again. If the person who asked the question feels that some other answer was good but didn't solve his/her case 100% then s/he can upvote those.

Comment: See mine: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1744886/raeen-hashemi?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=1

I have 9 zero accepted answers with 44 total. It is above 5 and above 20% of total and I did not get this badge. How is this possible?

Comment: @KlasMellbourn, I think it's because you spend time helping people (new users usually) with specific needs that are not likely to accept or even up-vote, (and you know this going in), but you help them out anyway.  It's questions that aren't likely to be viewed by many people because of their specificity.  Although, one likes the practice, and enjoys helping. It shows that you continue to answer questions despite the lack of reward or acknowledgement.  Obviously, we'd be happy to get those up-votes, or even have them ACCEPT the answer after admitting it worked.  The badge makes one feel good.

Comment: I just got this badge and I'm trying to figure out if its a good thing... On one hand, my answers were accepted, so I guess it is but on the other, no upvotes, so are my answers actually high quality answers though?

Comment: @kennytm Or users that want to give the answerer a chance at the Tenacious badge

Comment: @RaeinHashemi It's because you have to WAIT 10 days.

Answer (score 32):

This picture could help:

> [image: Score of 0 and Accepted Answer]

You should have this at least 5 times and 20% of your total answers. In other words, pray to not be upvoted on your accepted answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Have zero score on 20 percent of your total accepted answers (excluding CW and self-accept) (and 5 times). There is a **very** important thing about this badge. You have to **wait** 10 days and if you still have the required conditions, you get the badge. In other words, wait and stay not upvoted.

(**Note to all downvoters**: This IS the case on Stack Overflow, I don't know if it's a special example or it is the case on all sites (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/badge-suggestion-unsung-hero-5-accepted-answers-with-no-votes#56705), it is the case for Unsung Hero! And see this: [Tenacious problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85480/tenacious-problem#85483) where the asker should have the Tenacious badge but some of the answers are less than 10 days old) And see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tenacious-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded/57834#57834). I have a lot of evidence against the "awarded instantly" thing)