# Tenacious problem

Tags: support, badges, zero-score-badges

I have 27 accepted answers and 6 of them are with zero score

```
6/27 = 0.22 > 0.2
```

Why I don't have Tenacious badge?

Comment: Standard inquiry: how long has it been since you qualified for the Tenacious badge? Some badges may take up to 48 hours to be awarded.

Comment: I had `6/26` 2 days ago

Comment: You should keep silent. There are hordes here awaiting to impede your `tenacious` badge through a few cheap votes ...

Comment: @belisarius :-))))

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Only accepted answers [ten or more days old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tireless-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded/57834#57834) are counted against the Tenacious criteria. At least [one of your recently accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476436/i-want-to-make-array-of-checkbox-in-scrollviewer-control-in-wpf/5476756#5476756) does not yet qualify on this basis.

Comment: So I have to wait and hope no one votes on my answers?  Laaame :)