# What does the Unsung Hero badge mean, exactly?

Tags: discussion, badges, zero-score-badges

The description is:

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total.

Does that mean:

- 25% of all answers are zero-score + accepted
- 25% of all zero-score answers are accepted
- 25% of all accepted answers are zero-score
- something else?

Comment: It means the user is a hero but no one has sung about him.  Duh.

Comment: See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57244/unsung-hero-requirement

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it doesn’t actually answer the question — it has the same ambiguity as the badge description...

Answer (score 9):

You get the badge for having X accepted answers with a score of 0, and Y accepted answers in total, where

1. X ≥ 10 and
2. X/Y ≥ 0.25.

For both X and Y, "accepted answers" does not include self-accepts, deleted answers, and CW answers.

Comment: Hang on, so self-accepts and CW answers are *excluded* in the Y count but *included* in the X count? :)

Comment: 'where Y is the total number of your accepted answers' does that mean of any score or only the zero-score ones?

Comment: I hope my edit clarifies the situation.