# Clarity in definitions of Tenacious and Unsung Hero

Tags: feature-request, badges, wording, zero-score-badges

### Background

1. **Tenacious** is defined as "Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total"
2. **Unsung Hero** is defined as "Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total"

The mathematician in me twitches a little every time I read these definitions because of the ambiguity.

Does "of total" refer to "total accepted answers" or "total answers"?  Can we alter these definitions a bit to remove the ambiguity?

**Edit:**  Another good point to consider is the definition of "Zero score accepted answers".  While I doubt this happens often, if a user misconstrues this to mean "answers I have *accepted* that have zero scores" rather than "answers I have *provided* that have zero scores", it may actually encourage users to accept answers without up-voting them.

### Proposed Wording

1. **Tenacious** is defined as "Answers provided with zero score: more than 5 and 20% of total accepted answers"
2. **Unsung Hero** is defined as "Answers provided with zero score: more than 10 and 25% of total accepted answers"

Comment: [Answered here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57245/176080) but agree this should be made clearer.

Comment: I'm guessing self-accepts are excluded from both the numerator "zero score accepted answers" and denominator "total accepted answers" then?

Comment: [Yep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57834/176080), that seems to be it.

Comment: answers of mine have accepted with zero scores. How it will encourage users to accept answers without up-voting them?

Comment: Would you be interested in offering an alternative / more clear wording here, in your question?

Comment: I mean 'answers of mine have accepted with zero scores' and not "answers I have accepted that have zero scores".(according to your last edit) You will get badge if others accepting answers with zero score and not when you are accepting answers with zero score. And my question was how it will encourage users to accept answers without up-voting them if we write    "answers I have accepted that have zero scores"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "of total" refer to "total accepted answers" and not "total answers"?

And total accepted answers are:

- Only accepted answers older than 10 days are considered (otherwise tons of new users would get this)
- As long as they are not self accept
- And they are not wiki
- And they are not deleted

And it is **Zero score** accepted answers and not **Zero score accepted** answers.

Definition should be changed because new people may group words differently.

i.e.

1. Tenacious is defined as "Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total accepted answers"
2. Unsung Hero is defined as "Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total accepted answers"

Comment: Maybe it's just late, but I don't quite see the difference in your bold groupings here.

Comment: @jkschneider: You misunderstood this english also. Many users will. 1. 'Zero score' accepted answers: accepted answers having Zero score of all accepted answers 2. 'Zero score accepted' answers: answers accepted with zero score of all answers.

Comment: No offense to my native language, but it sucks :)